# Connect to remote vps server postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have vps server with postresql. I change settings to enable remote connections

1. listen_addresses = *
2. host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
3. sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp

Then i need to connect in python with psycopg2

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='fr3sto', user='**', password='**',host='***' )
```

In the host I write the address of my VPS. User and password are role data in postgres on vps.
But i recieve an error message `connection to server at "***", port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart the database after making the config changes?  The problem might be with your 1.  It wouldn't be with 2 or 3, as they would lead to different errors messages.

Comment: you must establish a ssh connection and tunnel the sql connection

Comment: @nbk can i connect to db without ssh tunnel?

Comment: a virtual private server should only be connected, by a secure connection, a open port, makes the sql server vulnerable. also every one can read what is transfered, which s also very bad